# using @ symbol with ftp stream in DirectoryIterator

Tags: php, ftp

I'm using DirectoryIterator class to list ftp content:
$a = new DirectoryIterator('ftp://user:password@host');

If there is an at "@" character in login, i get an error:
failed to open dir: operation failed

How i can escape @ symbol in login?

I try:
%40,
+
\@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) mandates the special characters like `@` should be urlencoded in the ftp:// scheme. So using `%40` in place of the @ in a password fragement would be correct.

But you just wanted the `user:password@` prefix before the hostname. Those don't need escaping. And it's already natively supported by the ftp fopen url wrapper:

```
$d = opendir("ftp://anonymous:nopwd@ftp.kernel.org/pub/");
print readdir($d);
```

Above ftp:// url works for me with [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/DirectoryIterator) too, but gives some obscure warning and different results. So I would test with the native functions first.

Answer (score 1):

I am not that sure you can use `DirectoryIterator` as `FTP` client

You may want to learn how to use [ftp_rawlist](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) to get a list of the given directory